# How to stop PHP from assuming string contains variable

Tags: php, string

I've been trying to find solution somewhere for this possibly simple fix but, I haven't been able to surprisingly.

How is it possible to stop PHP from assuming a variable is a part of a string. E.g.

The line of code is `$string = "slfnnwnfkw49828323$dgjkt^7ktlskegjejke";`
how do you stop PHP from thinking '`$dgjkt`' is a variable within the string when it's really a part of the full string as characters. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: No need to down-vote: just vote as an appropriate duplicate and move on..

Answer (score 2):

Use this string like `$sting = 'slfnnwnfkw49828323$dgjkt^7ktlskegjejke'`

Comment: Hope this link will explain this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: you're answering the question, so answer it.

Comment: Single quoted strings are the easiest way to specify string. This method in used when we want to the string to be exactly as it is written. When string is specified in single quotes PHP will not evaluate it or interpret escape characters except single quote with backslash (‘) and backslash(\) which has to be escaped. In double quoted strings other escape sequences are interpreted as well any variable will be replaced by their value.

Comment: @AdittyaVerma Please give credit when using others' material. http://programming-tips.in/php-what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings/

Comment: I didn't refer any material which you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ' instead of " otherwise php tries to find any variables inside your string

Answer (score 0):

Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that
>   variable names will be expanded. See string parsing for details:
>
> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.
>
> There are two types of syntax: a simple one and a complex one. The
>   simple syntax is the most common and convenient. It provides a way to
>   embed a variable, an array value, or an object property in a string
>   with a minimum of effort.
>
> The complex syntax can be recognised by the curly braces surrounding
>   the expression.